# Cannot reach Jenkins container from a seperate container with HTTP request

Tags: docker, jenkins, networking, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a service, `some-service`, that needs to make http requests to a `Jenkins` service - both running in separate Docker containers. My issue is that whenever I make a request, my connection is refused.

Both `some-service` and `Jenkins` are running on ports `3030` and `4040` with host names `some-service` and `jenkins`, respectively.

I can hit `Jenkins` successfully on my local machine outside of `some-service` with:

```
curl -v http://localhost:4040/
```

However, I cannot reach `Jenkins` from inside `some-service` using:

```
curl -v http://jenkins:4040/
```

I'm using this simple `Docker-compose.yaml` file to create both `some-service` and `Jenkins`:

```
version: '3'

services:

  some-service:
    container_name: service
    image: service:latest
    hostname: some-service
    build:
      context: service/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      GET_HOSTS_FROM: dns
    networks:
      - eg-net
    ports:
      - 3030:3030
    depends_on:
      - jenkins
    links:
      - jenkins
    labels:
      kompose.service.type: LoadBalancer

  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkinsci/blueocean
    restart: always
    hostname: jenkins
    networks:
      - eg-net
    ports:
      - 4040:8080
    volumes:
      - ./jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home

networks:
  eg-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Just successfully reached `Jenkins` from within `some-service` using `curl -v http://jenkins:8080/`, though I am not sure why this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access http://jenkins:4040/ from within your service because port 4040 is exposed **only to the host machine**. Thats why `curl -v http://localhost:4040/` on your host machine works.

If you want to access jenkins from within another container you have to use the port 8080 because this port is exposed within the network. So `curl -v http://jenkins:8080/` from within your service will work.

Hope this will clarify it.

Comment: That makes total sense. Thank you!